# How to shorten this CSS code?

Tags: css

I currently have a rather long list of images that I wish to apply a hover affect upon mouse-over to, my question is how can I possibly shorten this to one simple paragraph:

```css
/* ==========================================================================
   Images
   ========================================================================== */

/*
 * Add hover affect to structure page images..
 */
#st1 {
    opacity: 1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

#st1:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=75); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
#st2 {
    opacity: 1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

#st2:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=75); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

Comment: Read a basic tutorial on CSS, including how to use classes, and/or how to specify rules for a set of selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use an id specific to each image (i.e. `#st1` .. `#stx`) use a class like `.hover-effect` and add `class='hover-effect'` to all elements that should be affected by your hover.  Then, your CSS can look like this:

```
.hover-effect {
    opacity: 1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

.hover-effect:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=75); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For all images use same class:

```
<img src="file1" class="classname"/>
<img src="file2" class="classname"/>
<img src="file3" class="classname"/>
```

**CSS**:

```
.classname{
    opacity: 1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

.classname:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=75); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
#st1,#st2 {
    opacity: 1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

#st1:hover,#st2:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=75); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

If you can assign a class to the image tags, then instead of using id you can use class in the css rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use:

```
#st1,#st2{
    opacity: 1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
#st1:hover,#st2:hover{
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=75); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

or(if possible to add class name to elements):

```
.st{  
    opacity: 1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
.st:hover{    
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=75); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

Note: Since its better to minimise the usage of 'id' in HTML elements, second method is most recommended.